# Use Python Imaging Library to isolate a single channel

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So say I have an image, and I want to make it so that only the red channel shows up, and the image looks red, how would I do this using PIL? Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `Image.split()` operation from PIL to separate the image into bands:

```
img = Image.open("image.jpg")
red, green, blue = img.split()
```

If the image has an alpha channel (RGBA) the split function will aditionaly return that. More information [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.split).

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer. Instead of using im.split(), which converted the band to grayscale, I should've converted the Image to an array,multiplied the bands I don't want by 0, and then turned it back to an Image object.

Importing Image and numpy, I did the following:

```
a = Image.open("image.jpg")
a = numpy.array(a)
a[:,:,0] *=0
a[:,:,1] *=0
a = Image.fromarray(a)
a.show()
```

This would show a blue image.

Answer (score 2):

Late here, but because we're dealing with numpy, we can use boolean indexing.

```
def channel(img, n):
    """Isolate the nth channel from the image.

       n = 0: red, 1: green, 2: blue
    """
    a = np.array(img)
    a[:,:,(n!=0, n!=1, n!=2)] *= 0
    return Image.fromarray(a)
```

Comment: I don't think we are dealing with numpy, the OP was asking about PIL

Answer (score 1):

For people who are looking to extract a **single** channel from an image (as opposed to generating an image with R, G and B channels, but with the G and B channels all zero), you can do:

```
img = Image.open("image.jpg")
red = img.getchannel('R')
# OR
red = img.getchannel(0)  # Avoids internal lookup of 'R' in img.getbands()
```